# How can I draw binary tree switches?

Tags: diagrams, graphs

I need to draw a binary tree switch. How can I draw something similar to the picture below?
[image: Binary Tree Switch]

Comment: I assume the switch is the circle with the little lines inside.  Easy solution is to create a pic (page 251).  More challenging is to create a shape (page 1034).  Using TikZ that is.

Comment: Welcome! What have you tried? It isn't a tree, by the way. Ti*k*Z or pstricks or similar. Or draw it in your GUI application and just `\includegraphics{}`. Please provide a minimal example i.e. code for a small document which shows us which specific problem you're having. Otherwise, somebody may fancy your do-it-for-me, if you're lucky (if your image is attractive, challenging or cute you stand a better chance of getting somebody to do your work for you so maybe try changing the image to a duck or a kitten), or not, otherwise.

Comment: never mind, I got the source code from the author.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as solved in comments